# 'SwiftUI' how to change checkmark in `listview`

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change the checkmark image on `listview` row selection, but I'm not getting expected result from selection.

Below code I'm creating `listview` from the array todo items and added `tapGesture` to the row. When I'm selecting row I can able to change the `completed` value but not reflecting that on UI.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Todo] = todoItems
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Row(item: item) { item in
                item.completed.toggle()
                print(item.completed)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Row: View {
     let item: Todo
    
    var onTap: ((_ item: Todo) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.completed ? "checkmark.square.fill" :  "squareshape" )
                .foregroundColor(item.completed ? .green : .gray)
            Text(item.title).font(.headline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }.onTapGesture {
            onTap?(item)
        }
    }
}

class Todo: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Todo, rhs: Todo) -> Bool {
        lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
    
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
    
    init(title: String, completed: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.completed = completed
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
    }
}


let todoItems = [
    Todo(title: "$300", completed: false),
    Todo(title: "$550", completed: false),
    Todo(title: "$450", completed: false)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Todo` a `struct`. For data like this, it is much more preferable for it to be a `struct` rather than a `class`.

The `item` also doesn't need to be passed down, since you already get it in the `List`. I also used the `$` syntax within for `$items`, so `$item` is a `Binding` and you therefore can mutate `item`. Changing `item` is changing that element in `@State` variable `items`, therefore a view update occurs.

Your implementation for `Equatable` and `Hashable` on `Todo` was incorrect - because otherwise the view won't update if a `Todo` instance is the same, even with a different `completed` value. I added `Identifiable` to `Todo` anyway, so you can implicitly identify by `id`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Todo] = todoItems

    var body: some View {
        List($items) { $item in
            Row(item: item) {
                item.completed.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Row: View {
    let item: Todo
    let onTap: (() -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.completed ? "checkmark.square.fill" :  "squareshape" )
                .foregroundColor(item.completed ? .green : .gray)
            Text(item.title).font(.headline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }.onTapGesture {
            onTap?()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Todo: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool

    init(title: String, completed: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.completed = completed
    }
}
```